# why Java Assist library is not working in android?

Tags: java, android, android-sqlite

I want to implement , dynamic Creation of databases/Content_provider class for any user , 
for that i want java assist class , by which i am creating , dynamic classes for `databases` and `contentProvider` .

for that i have used `JavaAssist` library , and it is working perfect in Java , but `practising` in java i have switched to real implementation in Android , but hard luck `JavaAssist` is not working in Android .

Any suggestion !

**Edited** : after jon skeet , reply .

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_create_custom_database);

    ClassForHelp object = new ClassForHelp() ;
    object.createDatabaseWith_Assist() ;
}


    // In Another class .
public void createDatabaseWith_Assist ()
{
    ClassPool pool = ClassPool.getDefault();

    CtClass cc = pool.makeClass("DataBaseClass");

    try {
        //cc.writeFile( ""+android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() );
        cc.writeFile( );
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (CannotCompileException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (NotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


}
```

Comment: Must check that library project imported properly in your eclipse android

Comment: @PiyushGupta , thanks , for your reply , but i have implemented it in a same way in Java , both projects are created in Eclipse , and if it is not imported correctly then , "ClassPool" class will throw the compile time error .

Comment: When you have added it as a library project as a reference in your project then is it displayed as a Green mark indicated?

Comment: "cc.writeFile( );" , is a problem !